# sorting of hashes in perl

Tags: perl, sorting, hash, reference

I have an array of references to hashes:

```
@array=($ref1,$ref2,$ref3);
```

Each ref point to a hash with the same keys but different values.
I have to sort the hashes according to the values of KEY (one of keys in hashes).
Later I have to print out the values of all keys of all hashes but sorted.

Example:

```
%h1=(KEY=>1,name=>John,sport=>football);
%h2=(KEY=>52,name=>Kate,sport=>football);
%h3=(KEY=>7,name=>April,sport=>basketball);
```

As a result I want to get it in the order:

> %h1,%h3,%h2

Comment: Well, have you read the documentation for `sort`? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example:

```
use strict;
use warnings; 

my %h1=(KEY=>1,name=>'John',sport=>'football');
my %h2=(KEY=>52,name=>'Kate',sport=>'football');
my %h3=(KEY=>7,name=>'April',sport=>'basketball');
my @array=(\%h1,\%h2,\%h3);

for my $h (sort {$a->{KEY} <=> $b->{KEY} } @array) {
    print join(",", map { "$_, $h->{$_}"} keys %$h ), "\n";
}
```

**Output**

```
KEY, 1,name, John,sport, football
KEY, 7,name, April,sport, basketball
KEY, 52,name, Kate,sport, football
```